# What is a Kernel-based Virtual Machine?

Tags: linux, cloud, kvm

According to linux-kvm.org:

> KVM for (Kernel-based Virtual Machine) is  a full virtualization
>   solution for Linux on x86 hardware.

However, I have no clue about the meaning of virtualization in this context or its benefits. I am a beginner and these buzzword-filled definitions are not helping.

Comment: You probably know what a "full virtualized system" means. For every virtualization you obviously need some form of support on the "host system" where the virtualized system is executed on. KVM offers such support right on kernel level, not on user space. That has a number of advantages and disadvantages. It also requires some preconditions on hardware level to be fulfilled though (read: the CPU has to offer such a mode).

Answer (score 1):

KVM is a virtualization infrastructure for the Linux kernel that turns it into a hypervisor. It was merged into the Linux kernel mainline in kernel version 2.6.20, which was released on February 5, 2007. KVM requires a processor with hardware virtualization extension.

you can find more information [here](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Main_Page)

Answer (score 0):

KVM is a virtualization technology which can run Another OS onto your current linux.

Much like VMWare and other virtualization technologies out there.